# Brand new Ubuntu 23.04 installation "Does not have a release file" on update

Tags: apt, kylin

I have a brand new installation of Ubuntu 23.04.  I'm trying to do "sudo apt update" and getting the following error:

The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntukylin-members/ukui/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to resolve this?

I could just remove the package listing, but it seems like that package must be important and I'd prefer to get it to work properly

Thanks!

Comment: A brand new installation will not come with third party repositories, you added this repository yourself, so your installation is not brand new but altered. Obviously you can not use this repository with your version of Ubuntu, so remove it.